# GCC: Print used functions during program/library run

Tags: linux, function, gcc

Is it possible to print a list of all functions used during a program run?
The program and the library used by the program is compiled with GCC without optimization.

The reason for this list is that I'd like to optimize a library which has a lot of unused functions (the library is really huge and I need only a few functions).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can compile them again you could use a profiler such as [gprof](http://www.cs.utah.edu/dept/old/texinfo/as/gprof_toc.html) or [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/cl-manual.html) (with its callgrind tool). I think you wouldn't need a new compiling if you use valgrind.

Answer (score 1):

If its dynamic library (`*.so`) try `ltrace`. For example to see how `ls` uses `libc`:

```
ltrace --library /lib64/libc.so.6 ls
```

`gprof` can be an option too.

Answer (score 0):

`gcov` (compile with `gcc -ftest-coverage -fprofile-arcs`) will say this too.